# In Python, what is the difference between open(file).read() and subprocess(['cat', file]) and is there a preference for one over the other?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to read RAM usage from `/proc/meminfo`. There are two basic ways to do this that I can think of.

**Use a shell command**

```
output = subprocess.check_output('cat /proc/meminfo', shell=True)
# or output = subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/proc/meminfo'])
lines = output.splitlines()
```

**Use open()**

```
with open('/proc/meminfo') as meminfo:
    output = meminfo.read()
lines = output.splitlines()
```

My question is what is the difference between the two methods? Is there a significant performance difference? My assumption is that using `open()` is the preferred method, since using a shell command is a bit hackish and may be system dependent, but I can't find any information on this so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Unnecessary use of `cat` is considered bad practice even when writing shell scripts. :)

Comment: ...not joking about that at all; see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html -- in general, `cat foo | bar` is a much less efficient way of writing `bar <foo`.

Comment: ...but if you *were* going to use `cat`, the version without a shell (commented out in your question) is the only one that's safe to use with unknown (ie. user-provided) filenames. Think about what `subprocess.check_output('cat %s' % filename, shell=True)` would do with a filename of `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)/hello.txt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...so, let's look at what `output = subprocess.check_output('cat /proc/meminfo', shell=True)` does:

- Creates a FIFO pair with `mkfifo()`, and spawns a shell running `sh -c 'cat /proc/meminfo'` writing to the input end of the FIFO (while the Python interpreter itself watches for output on the other end, either using the `select()` call or blocking IO operations). This means opening `/bin/sh`, opening all the libraries it depends on, etc.
- The shell parses those arguments as code. This can be dangerous if, instead of opening `/proc/meminfo`. you're instead opening `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)/pwned.txt`.
- The shell forks a subprocess (optionally; shells may have an implicit `exec`), which then uses the `execve` system call to invoke `/bin/cat` with an argv of `['cat', '/proc/meminfo']` -- meaning that `/bin/cat` is again loaded as an executable, with its dynamic libraries, with all the performance overhead that implies.
- `/bin/cat` then opens `/proc/meminfo`, reads from it, and writes to its stdout
- The shell, if it did not use the implicit-`exec` optimization, waits for the `/bin/cat` executable to finish and exit using a `wait()`-family syscall.
- The Python interpreter reads from the remote end of the FIFO until it provides an EOF (which will not happen until after `cat` has closed its output pipeline, potentially by exiting), and then uses a `wait()`-family call to retrieve information on how the shell it spawned exited, checking that exit status to determine whether an error occurred.

---

Now, let's look at what `open('/proc/meminfo').read()` does:

- Opens the file using the `open()` syscall.
- Reads the file using the `read()` syscall.
- Drops the reference count on the file, allowing it to be closed (either immediately or on a future garbage collection pass) with the `close()` syscall.

One of these things is much, *much*, **much** more efficient and generally sensible than the other.

Comment: (related) So `shell=False` is preferred? E.g. `subprocess.check_output('df')` is better than `subprocess.check_output('df', shell=True)`?

Comment: `shell=False` is preferred, yes. `subprocess.check_output(['df'])` is preferred to `subprocess.check_output('df', shell=True)`.

Comment: @JacobPhillips, ...it's both a performance issue and a correctness one: If you want to pass literal content through with `shell=True`, you need to write the script passed as the first argument to retrieve that content out-of-band. For instance, you could do the following safely (though still needlessly inefficiently): `subprocess.check_output(['cat "$1"', filename], shell=True)`, because the variable is on the shell's argv rather than in its `-c` argument and won't be parsed as code.